# Dbus instrospection incomplete for UDisks2?

Tags: java, dbus

I am using the java dbus interface. As it is not complete, we have to use the dbus introspection tool to generate xml files that will be converted into Java classes.

I want to be able to receive signals when a drive is inserted or removed from the system.

For that, I found that the signals InterfacesAdded and InterfacesRemoved are what I am searching for.

I have used this command to generate the xml introspection file :

```
gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks2 --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks2 --xml
```

It have generated a file, that I have converted with this command :

```
CreateInterface --system --no-ignore-builtin --create-files org.freedesktop.UDisks2.xml
```

I am now able to receive the InterfacesAdded signal, but not the InterfacesRemoved one.

There seems to be a problem, this signal want's to give some information that are in the block_devices node. But for this node the xml file is empty :

```
<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN"
                      "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<!-- GDBus 2.66.2 -->
<node>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties">
    ... snip ...
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager">
    <method name="GetManagedObjects">
      <arg type="a{oa{sa{sv}}}" name="object_paths_interfaces_and_properties" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <signal name="InterfacesAdded">
      <arg type="o" name="object_path"/>
      <arg type="a{sa{sv}}" name="interfaces_and_properties"/>
    </signal>
    <signal name="InterfacesRemoved">
      <arg type="o" name="object_path"/>
      <arg type="as" name="interfaces"/>
    </signal>
  </interface>
  <node name="Manager"/>
  <node name="drives"/>
  <node name="block_devices"/>
</node>
```

And as such the java code don't know how to create the signal.

What could I do for that ?

Comment: _"this signal want's to give some information that are in the block_devices node"_ -- how did you come to this conclusion? If the java tool you are using can't cope with additional nodes, try removing them from the xml manually.

Comment: Empty node are not transposed into a class by the CreateInterface tool. So removing it from the xml will not change anything. My conclusion come from the exception : org.freedesktop.dbus.exceptions.DBusException: Failed to create proxy object for /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb exported by :1.75. Reason: Could not find an interface to cast to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the core misunderstanding is this: You generate interface files for object `/org/freedesktop/UDisks2` but then in your code you use those interface files to create proxies for interfaces implemented by `/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb`. These objects implement different interfaces.

You will need interface definitions for all interfaces you create proxies for. I can't give the exact commands to do that with introspection but you can use the same method to generate them as long as you find a suitable object. As an example:

```
gdbus introspect --system --xml \
    --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks2 \
    --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/nvme0n1
```

produces the interface definition for `org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block` and `org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable` on my machine.

That said, UDisks2 does seem to have all of the `org.freedesktop.UDisks2.*` interfaces available in source code: [org.freedesktop.UDisks2.xml](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/blob/master/data/org.freedesktop.UDisks2.xml).

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed I had to export Block definitions (and do a major update from 2.7.2 to 3.2.3).